# Deployment template language expression evaluation failed: 'Unable to parse language expression ': expected token 'EndOfData' and actual 'Comma'.'

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-application-gateway

This is the arm template, I am trying to add multiple routing rules with and without redirectConfiguration as below

```
{
  "name": "requestRoutingRules",
  "count": "[length(parameters('RoutingRulesObject'))]",
  "input": {
    "name": "[parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].name]",
    "properties": {
      "ruleType": "[parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.ruletype]",
      "httpListener": {
        "id": "[if(empty(parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.httpListener.id), json('null'), parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.httpListener.id)]"
      },
      "backendAddressPool": {
        "id": "[if(empty(parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.backendAddressPool.id), json('null'), parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.backendAddressPool.id)]"
      },
      "backendHttpSettings": {
        "id": "[if(empty(parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.backendHttpSettings.id), json('null'), parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.backendHttpSettings.id)]"
      },
      "[if(not(empty(parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.redirectConfiguration.id))), 'redirectConfiguration']": {
        "id": "[parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.redirectConfiguration.id]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

trying to add multiple routing rules with and without redirectConfiguration as well other properties too

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me for adding the multiple routing rules with and without redirect Configuration. However, there is a one single part missing from the code: the `redirectconfiguration` block.

```bash
"redirectConfiguration": []
```

*I modified your code as below and it worked as expected.*

```bash
{
  "name": "requestRoutingRules",
  "count": "[length(parameters('RoutingRulesObject'))]",
  "input": {
    "name": "[parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].name]",
    "properties": {
      "ruleType": "[parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.ruletype]",
      "httpListener": {
        "id": "[if(empty(parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.httpListener.id), json('null'), parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.httpListener.id)]"
      },
      "backendAddressPool": {
        "id": "[if(empty(parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.backendAddressPool.id), json('null'), parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.backendAddressPool.id)]"
      },
      "backendHttpSettings": {
        "id": "[if(empty(parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.backendHttpSettings.id), json('null'), parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.backendHttpSettings.id)]"
      },
      "redirectConfiguration": {
      "id":  "[if(not(empty(parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.redirectConfiguration.id))), parameters('RoutingRulesObject')[copyIndex('requestRoutingRules')].properties.redirectConfiguration.id, json('null')]"
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

*Output:*

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/applicationgateways?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) for better understanding.